# How to read Soap XML Data

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap, xsd, xmlreader

How can i read this response which is recive in Soap XML ERROR_CODE,PROPOSAL_NO and CoverDtl.

i have try two three but it is not working

```
For Each node As XmlNode In xmlNodes
    strReceipt_ACKCODE = node.SelectSingleNode("PROPOSAL_NO").InnerText
Next
```

````
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GeneratePCCVProposalResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GeneratePCCVProposalResult>
                <POL_SYS_ID>123456</POL_SYS_ID>
                <PROPOSAL_NO>123456/123456/22/x/123456</PROPOSAL_NO>
                <VehicleIDV>45896</VehicleIDV>
                <ERROR_DESC>Proposal created successfully......!</ERROR_DESC>
                <ERROR_CODE>0</ERROR_CODE>
                <CoverDtlList>
                    <CoverDtl>
                        <CoverDesc>BASIC OD COVER</CoverDesc>
                        <Premium>12494.63</Premium>
                        <Type />
                    </CoverDtl>
                    <CoverDtl>
                        <CoverDesc>DETARIFF DISCOUNT ON BASIC OD</CoverDesc>
                        <Premium>8746.24</Premium>
                        <Type>LESS</Type>
                    </CoverDtl>                    
                </CoverDtlList>
            </GeneratePCCVProposalResult>
        </GeneratePCCVProposalResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>```
````

Comment: Please explain more clearly.  I cannot work out what your goals are. Please also explain what happens when you execute the For Each in your question.

Comment: @kimbert can you give solution how can i read ERROR_CODE.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not a .Net dev. If you want help, you should edit your question and show the exact result that your code is returning. And explain what you want it to return. Then somebody else will be able to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.